# Cut specific part

Tags: scripts

I need to cut out specific parts from a text..

Here a small part of it:

```
                    </span>
                    <span class="package" data-subid="570168" data-appid="1597920" data-parent="544810">
                        <a href="/sub/570168/">570168</a>
                        , // <button class="js-remove btn btn-danger">[Hide]</button>
                        KARDS - Anniversary Edition

                    </span>
                    <span class="package" data-subid="569859" data-appid="1606900" data-parent="-1277130">
                        <a href="/sub/569859/">569859</a>
                        , // <button class="js-remove btn btn-danger">[Hide]</button>
                        Deathbound Demo

                    </span>
                     ...
```

I need the number inside of the data-appid="" exported into the following format:
"1597920,1606900"

Is there an easy way to do this kind of job?

Thanks for all your assistance!

Cheers

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly. How does this relate to Ubuntu?

Comment: Use python or perl for this. The split command. Coding questions are off topic though

Comment: Start with `grep -Eo 'data-appid="[0-9]+"  | cut '-d"' -f2`

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to parse `html` or `xml` with `grep`, rather use a proper parser.

I'd use `python` and  `BeautifulSoup` module. Put the following in a script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
soup = BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin, 'html.parser')
for p in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "package"}):
    print(p["data-appid"])
```

Then run

```bsh
< file.html python3 test.py
```

or if you try to parse a webiste:

```bsh
curl exampel.com/some_page | python3 test.py
```

---

You need to install `bs4` module, e.g. using `pip` or `pip3`:

```bsh
pip3 install bs4
#or
pip install bs4
```